# gmail working great on laravel site, trouble swapping with domain email creds from register.com

Tags: laravel, email

I'm using my personal gmail to send messages from my laravel 5.1 site (working great), and I'd like to update this to send from a domain mailbox I have through register.com (aka web.com).

I'm not finding a great resource on web.com, only this: https://knowledge.web.com/Support/70044/70044/en-US/Article/View/24/How-Do-I-Get-Started-with-POP3-and-IMAP/0

But it looks like the port/driver stays the same, so I've swapped the bottom three values in my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_HOST=smtp.ourbigfamilytree.com
MAIL_USERNAME=diane@ourbigfamilytree.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=(my password)
```

I did these to make sure the new values get used:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

In mail.php, I make use of those env variables (I don't override them), and I updated the 'from' address to match to make sure it's consistent:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'diane@ourbigfamilytree.com', 'name' => 'Diane Kaplan'],
```

When I trigger an email I get:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.ourbigfamilytree.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?  I've heard that godaddy 'blocks' the smtp ports, so I hope it's not something like that- anyone know a good way to determine that? I wasn't able to find the answer on their knowledgebase, but I also haven't messed with email much so I'm not sure I'm using the right search terms.

thanks in advance for any help/ideas- 
Diane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the exact answer, but in the long run you will have much less trouble using actual mail service providers rather than hooking into gmail like that.

Mailgun is excellent, easy to set up with a custom domain, and if you have such little traffic that using gmail was an initial solution, you will most likely fall within the free tier of Mailgun.

https://mailgun.com

Bonus points: Laravel has Mailgun front of mind, so very easy to set up.

Comment: That's great news! I hadn't realized mailgun has a free option, but I must have been thinking of mandrill. I'll have a fresh look at mailgun, and yes it's encouraging that it's so commonly used with laravel. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. If the answer helped, feel free to upvote/mark as correct as future people hitting this question will know it resolved the issue at hand

Comment: Will do- will dig in this weekend and reply back

Comment: Awesome glad to hear. And no worries